# How can I message someone on this forum?

Tags: support, status-completed

How can I message someone on this forum?
I saw a very interesting point of view made by one of the users here. Do I need to first acquire enough reputations points to contact a user here?

Comment: Just please keep in mind the point of the site is decidedly not socializing or networking.

Comment: [You can't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user). [By design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users).

Comment: why was this downvoted? it's a totally reasonable question

Answer (score 1):

See: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/205264)

Some important points from that link:

- Instant / private messaging is not (and won't be) available.
- Some users are active in [public chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), but Philosophy.SE is pretty dead on chat.
- You can comment on posts (even of other users, when you earn more reputation first).
- Some people have contact information on their profile. But take care, because [not everyone likes to be contacted there without good reason](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/08/22/stack-overflow-and-personal-emails/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least 20 pts reputation, you can post a message in chat starting with the @Username format, and it should appear in [Username]'s inbox.  It will also be publicly visible to everyone.  There is no way to send a private direct message.

Comment: good friendly answer :)